# What's the formula to calculate the height of a given text?

Tags: fonts, truetype, opentype

OTF documentation says:

> USE_TYPO_METRICS  If set, it is strongly recommended that applications use OS/2.sTypoAscender - OS/2.sTypoDescender + OS/2.sTypoLineGap as the default line spacing for this font.

Dejavu-serif-condensed-italic is a font that has set this bit, so the given formula works.

But all other fonts I've tested so far have not set it.

When I tried a way to calculate the height it is working for one font, but not for the others.
Then I've used a different way, that worked for another font, but not for the font it worked before - and so on.

[image: Roboto-Regular]

This is Roboto-Regular, the formula usWinAscent + usWinDescent is working with it, as you can see on the image.

[image: OpenSans-Regular]

This picture shows OpenSans-Regular with the same calculation; here the result does not fit with the text.

[image: JetBrainsMono-Regular]

The picture shows the calculated height for JetBrainsMono-Regular.

An interesting point of this font is, that the line gap from the hhea or os2 table is 0.
YMin, descender, sTypoDescender and usWinDescent have the value 300 or -300.
YMax, ascender, sTypoAscender and usWinAscent share the absolute value 1020.

So all logical calculations lead to 1320 font design units.
By testing it manually, the result should be 1300 to return a correct line height.

So what's an accurate formula to calculate the height of a line?

Comment: What's your criteria for determining :correct"? How did you decide that 1300 should be expected?

Comment: @PeterConstable Thanks for replying. "Correct means, that the border of the rectangle fits with the descender of the last sentence. I got the value just by testing it. The right border aligns exactly to the text when using adw and subtracting kerning; for all fonts I've tested so far.

Comment: There isn't a "correct" line height. Line height could be set to whatever. The font provides data that can be used for a recommended default line height. Read the description for [usWinAscent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#uswinascent), which should be helpful.

Comment: @PeterConstable So, if I want to center the font in a coordinate system and do page breaks in PDF, what's the way to go then? I need accurate width and height for that.

Comment: Measuring line lengths and deciding on a line height are two very different things. Again, the OS/2 data gives recommended default values that you can use for line height, but you can use other line height if that better suits the situation. But for line length (in horizontal line layout), that has to be computed as a result of layout from the advance widths and placements of the glyphs on the line.

Comment: Based on your description, you're not actually interested in the "correct height", you're interested in getting the minimal bounding box for a text. Those two things are not technically related =)